# How to find absolute NSView frame position in window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a complicated hierarchy of NSViews, how can I find the frame of a view in the window or be able to check if a point in the window is in the views frame?

I tried something like this

```
NSPoint windowOrigin = [[window contentView] convertPoint:NSMakePoint(0,0) fromView:myView];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Send `convertRect:toView:` with the second argument set to nil:

```
NSRect viewFrameInWindowCoords = [myView convertRect: [myView bounds] toView: nil];
```

On a second thought, if you need to perform hit testing, you might want to do the opposite:

```
NSView *viewUnderPoint = [[window contentView] hitTest: locationInWindow];
```